# empty numeric columns populated with previous numeric column value

Tags: ssis

I have a text file with more than one table's data in it (different column counts). I import the whole row as one column. Based on a conditional split, the rows are dispersed to their correct flow. I use a script component to split the single column values (row) into the correct columns for that table and give it as output columns. All of this is working fine, and data looks fine.

My problem comes in with some numeric fields. When a numeric field has no values in it, it ends up in the table with another column's numeric value.

I have put data viewers everywhere, in not one of them there is data for the column that should be empty. When I look in the table itself, there it is... data from another column.

- It is not the mappings, I checked it a dozen times.
- It is not the names that are the same or something like that.
- There is no data according to dataviewers anywhere in the load process.
- There is no hidden code anywhere.
- I droped and recreated the table.
- I displayed a messagebox with the column's (that is supposed to be empty) assigned "column value", and no data, like expected.
- I used a derived column, same result, no data in dataviewers, but eventualy data in the table.

I also created another test table with those numeric fields as varchar. When I do this, the column is empty (like expected). When I change it to numeric, the field is populated again. (If it was the other way around I could understand).

What can be te reason for this? It is driving me insane.

**EDIT**

Script code:

```
 //C#
 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
    ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    char[] seperator = { '|' };
    Byte[] ByteBlob;
    String[] ColumnValue;
    ByteBlob = Row.Column0.GetBlobData(0, (int)(Row.Column0.Length));
    ColumnValue = enc.GetString(ByteBlob).Split(seperator);
    Row.OutputColumn0 = ColumnValue[0];
    Row.OutputColumn1 = ColumnValue[1];
///etc
```

Just to give an example of what it does, this is what a row would look like in a sence.

Column names:

Source|Tablename|Value1|Value2|Description|Value3|Description2|Value4

Actual Data:

ABC|Revenue|123,456|729,537|MisterX||None|

Data in Table:

ABC|Revenue|123,456|729,537|MisterX|729,537|None|729,537

Comment: could you please post the script component code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using Row.ColumnX_IsNull , for example if (Row.Column0_IsNull) {youroutputcolumn=null} else {...}

Comment: Thanks. This does give the results needed. I was still hoping there is an explination for the behaviour.